Xcode sign App with included Executables and Libraries
I have written a small launcher application for MacOS using Xcode and Swift for another bigger app. The app builds fine and is signable using Xcode automatic signing. Now, I want to copy the prebuild binaries, libraries and other sources from the bigger app into the launcher application bundle. Therefore, I am using a "Build Phase Script", which copies the files into the Contents/ directory of the application bundle. This happens before signing. The prebuild app was already signed.
Now, I cannot sign the whole application bundle. It always crashes, saying bundle format unrecognized, invalid or unsuitable.
Where is the problem?
